Vertical lines from 3D surface plot to 2D contour plot
I have a 3D surface plot and a 2D contour plot in the xy plane. I want to create a few vertical lines from the surface plot to the computer plot (ideally, one vertical line per contour).
Sample requirement (copied from here):

However, I am not able to achieve a similar plot as above. My dummy minimum working example is below in which I have added a red vertical line with hard-coded code, but i would like to have similar vertical lines.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

# Create a quadratic surface
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2 + Y**2  # Quadratic surface
Z = Z + 20

# Mask a circular region (e.g., radius > 2)
mask = (X**2 + Y**2) > 4
Z_masked = np.ma.masked_where(mask, Z)

# Create plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the surface
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_masked, cmap=cm.viridis, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.8)

# Add contours on the XY plane at Z_min level
z_min = Z_masked.min() - 20
contour = ax.contour(X, Y, Z_masked, zdir='z', offset=z_min, colors='black', linewidths=1)

# Calculate the center of the valid region
valid_mask = ~Z_masked.mask
x_valid = X[valid_mask]
y_valid = Y[valid_mask]
z_valid = Z_masked[valid_mask]

# Find the approximate center
x_center = np.mean(x_valid)
y_center = np.mean(y_valid)
z_center = np.mean(z_valid)

# Plot the vertical line in red
ax.plot([x_center, x_center], [y_center, y_center], [z_min, z_center],
        color='red', linewidth=2, alpha=0.9)

# Add markers for clarity
ax.scatter(x_center, y_center, z_center, color='red', s=50, label='Surface Center')
ax.scatter(x_center, y_center, z_min, color='red', s=50, label='Contour Center')

# Labels and legend
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
ax.legend()

# Show plot
plt.show()


print


The contour object has the attributes levels and get_paths that lists respectively the value of each iso-contour and the coordinates of its points (via the vertices attribute of the paths objects):
contour = ax.contour(X, Y, Z_masked, zdir='z', offset=z_min, colors='black', linewidths=1)

# Get the coordinates of one point per contour
pointsX, pointsY, pointsZ = [], [], []
for i, (level, path) in enumerate(zip(contour.levels, contour.get_paths())):
    if len(path):
        pointsX.append(path.vertices[5+25*i][0])
        pointsY.append(path.vertices[5+25*i][1])
pointsZ = [X**2 + Y**2 + 20 for (X, Y) in zip(pointsX, pointsY)]

# Plot the points
ax.scatter(pointsX, pointsY, z_min, color='red', s=50, label='Contour Center')
ax.scatter(pointsX, pointsY, pointsZ, color='red', s=50, label='Contour Center')
# Plot the vertical line in red
for i in range(len(pointsX)):
    ax.plot([pointsX[i], pointsX[i]], [pointsY[i], pointsY[i]], [z_min, pointsZ[i]],
            color='red', linewidth=2, alpha=0.9)



I tried to add your code into my code but it is throwing an exception, Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'QuadContourSet' object has no attribute 'get_paths'. Could you maybe try to post the whole code, just in case I am making some mistake.

Their code works fine for me. What version of matplotlib are you using (import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__))? I'm using 3.9.2.

@jared I am using 3.7.1

Since in version 3.8 collections attributes are deprecated and that they will be removed in 3.10, I used set_path() instead (I have 3.9.2). So probably this solution will not work for Matplotlib versions  below 3.8.

ok, I found a second method. Does it work on computer if you replace the for loop definition by this:   for i, path in enumerate(ax.collections[1]._paths):

@rehaqds each element of the collections attribute was a PathCollection so you should be able to use get_paths on there.

@jared: by using matplotlib version 3.10, it worked.
